# Mount point permissions changing after `mount -a`

Tags: linux, permissions, raspberry-pi, nfs, fstab

I am using my raspberry pi as a plex server and have having serious problems with one of the shared folder...

---

**Related to my Synology NAS**

All three are on my local network Synology NAS:

- "music" is directly on the raid drives (and is the shared folder I have problems with)
- "tv" and "movies" are stored on a USB drive plugged into the NAS

I have configured my NAS NFS Permissions the same for all three shared folders:

- Explicity local IP of the raspberry pi
- read-only permissions
- No mapping/squashing of users
- security is "sys"
- Async
- non-privileged ports allowed
- cross-mount allowed

---

**Related to permissions & fstab on my raspberry pi**

The relevant part of my `etc/fstab` is as follows:

```
102.168.1.1.140:/volumeUSB1/usbshare1-2/MEDIA/MOVIES    /nas/movies   nfs   auto,defaults,nofail 0 0
102.168.1.1.140:/volumeUSB1/usbshare1-2/MEDIA/MOVIES    /nas/tv       nfs   auto,defaults,nofail 0 0
102.168.1.1.140:/volume1/music                          /nas/music    nfs   auto,defaults,nofail 0 0
```

I have each of the follow mount points created

- `/nas/tv` (mounts and plex can find media within it)
- `/nas/movies` (mounts and plex can find media within it)
- `/nas/music`  (mounts and **I can browse and see the files on the the raspberry pi itself but plex itself can't find any content**)

Before running `sudo mount -a`, all three have the following user/group settings:

- user as "root" (uid=116)
- group as "plex"(gid=4096)

...and then after running `sudo mount -a`:

MOVIES and TV:

- user as "1024" (uid=1024)
- group as "users" (gid=100)

MUSIC:

- user as root (uid=0)
- group as "root" (gid=0)

Comment: Have you tried to set user and group as fourth field in fstab (see manpage)? (i.e. `102.168.1.1.140:/volumeUSB1/usbshare1-2/MEDIA/MOVIES    /nas/movies   nfs   auto,defaults,nofail,uid=root,gid=plex 0 0`)

Answer (score 2):

That's normal. After mounting a filesystem, the mountpoint is completely overlayed, so `/nas/tv` now represents the root directory of the filesystem (or network share) that you just mounted.

(But even if that didn't happen, the permissions of the directory would have *no effect* on permissions of the individual files inside it. So your approach is doubly useless.)

There is no generic built-in mechanism for overriding ownership and permissions of a whole filesystem, but you can install `bindfs` for that.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply...! So is `bindfs` the correct way to handle this or should I be changing ownership/group of `volume1/music` directory and files on the NAS itself?

Comment: Changing ownership on the NAS itself would be best – if possible. (That is, if you don't have the complex situation where different clients need different UIDs for the same share...)